# How to build a bidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to push values onto an array like so:

```
$scoreValues[$i][] = $percent ;
$scoreValues[$i][] = '<span id="item'.$i.'" class="suggestElement" data-entityid="'.$row['id'].'" data-match="'.$percent.'">'.rawurldecode($row['name']).'</span>' ;
```

I basically want to link together the $percent with the string, so I get an output like:

```
array (0 > array('46.5', '<span etc etc')
```

I then plan to sort by the percent sub-array so I have the highest scoring strings at the top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/96759/), [how to create a multidimensional array PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8638051/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use two arrays :

```
$percents[$i] = $percent;
$scores[$i] = "<span....>");
```

Or one array, but indexed like this

```
$data = new arrray('percents' => array(), 'scores' => array());
$data['percents'][$i] = $percent;
$data['scores'][$i] = "<span....>");
```

Once this is done, you then sort your arrays using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php) :

```
array_multisort(
   $data['percents'], SORT_DESC,
   $data['scores']);
```

Comment: Didn't know about array_multisort, makes things a lot simpler for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line you need to specify the index of the second array:

```
$scoreValues[$i][$j] = '<span id="item'.$i.'" class="suggestElement" data-entityid="'.$row['id'].'" data-match="'.$percent.'">'.rawurldecode($row['name']).'</span>' ;
```

So you basically need 2 counters, one for the external array ($i) and on for the internal array ($j).

**EDIT:**

You got me a bit confused with the question, seems like what you need is not a multi dimensinal array but rather a simple array:

```
$scoreValues[$percent] = '<span id="item'.$i.'" class="suggestElement" data-entityid="'.$row['id'].'" data-match="'.$percent.'">'.rawurldecode($row['name']).'</span>' ;
```

Please note that this requires `$percent` to be unique.

Comment: Your edit requires `$percent` to be unique - can that be guaranteed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$val = array(
    'percent' => $percent,
    'html' => '<span id="item' . $i .
              '" class="suggestElement" data-entityid="'.$row['id'].
              '" data-match="'.$percent.'">'.rawurldecode($row['name']).
              '</span>'
);
// This just pushes it onto the end of the array
$scoreValues[] = $val ;
// Or you can insert it at an explicit location
//$scoreValues[$i] = $val;
```